# Filtering outliers within each category of categorical data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I'm new to pandas/seaborn/etc and attempting to graph a subset of my data in a different style (using seaborn), using something like the example here https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html :

```
>>> ax = sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="smoker",
...                    data=tips, jitter=True,
...                    palette="Set2", dodge=True)
```

[image]

My goal is to plot only the outliers *within each `x`/`hue` dimension*, i.e. for the example shown I'd be using 8 different percentile cutoffs for the 8 different columns of points displayed.

I have a dataframe like:

```
        Cat  RPS   latency_ns
0       X    100     909423.0
1       X    100   14747385.0
2       X    1000  14425058.0
3       Y    100    7107907.0
4       Y    1000  21466101.0
...     ...  ...   ...
```

And I want to filter this data, leaving only the upper 99.9th percentile outliers.

I've found I can do:

```
df.groupby([dim1_label, dim2_label]).quantile(0.999)
```

To get something like:

```
                                         latency_ns
Cat                          RPS                   
X                            10 RPS    6.463337e+07
                             100 RPS   4.400980e+07
                             1000 RPS  6.075070e+07
Y                            100 RPS   3.958944e+07
Z                            10 RPS    5.621427e+07
                             100 RPS   4.436208e+07
                             1000 RPS  6.658783e+07
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here with a merge/filter operation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example I created to guide you. I hope it is helpful.

Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

#create a sample data frame
n = 1000
prng = np.random.RandomState(123)

x = prng.uniform(low=1, high=5, size=(n,)).astype('int')
#print(x[:10])
#[3 2 1 3 3 2 4 3 2 2]

y = prng.normal(size=(n,))
#print(y[:10])
#[ 1.32327371 -0.00315484 -0.43065984 -0.14641577  1.16017595 -0.64151234
#-0.3002324  -0.63226078 -0.20431653  0.2136956 ]

z = prng.binomial(n=1,p=2/3,size=(n,))
#print(z[:10])
#[1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]

#analagously to the smoking example, my df x maps day,
#y maps to total bill, and z maps to is smoker (or not)
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':x,'y':y,'z':z})

#df.head()

df_filtered = pd.DataFrame()

#df.groupby.quantile([0.9]) returns a scalar, unless you want to plot only a single point, use this
#if you want to plot values that are within the lower and upper bounds, then some
#conditional filtering is required, see the conditional filtering I wrote below
for i,j in df.groupby([x, z]):
    b = j.quantile([0,0.9]) #use [0.999,1] in your case
    lb = b['y'].iloc[0]
    ub = b['y'].iloc[1]
    df_temp = j[(j['y']>=lb)&(j['y']<=ub)]
    df_filtered = pd.concat([df_filtered,df_temp])


#print(df_filtered.count())
#x    897
#y    897
#z    897
#dtype: int64
```

Output

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.stripplot(x='x', y='y', hue='z',
data=df_filtered, jitter=True,
palette="Set2", dodge=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]